# Раскрывающийся список дерево js

Tags: javascript, список, списки, дерево

Есть переменная в которой хранится очень много данных.
Я пытаюсь организовать раскрывающийся список дерево. Пример приведен ниже.
Не понимаю почему список не показывает все пункты полностью.
А только некоторые..

```js
window.onload = function() {
  docs.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
    for (i = 0; i <= 21; i++) {
      var d = document.createElement("div");
      document.body.appendChild(d);
      d.id = "Node" + i;
      d.innerHTML = '<div class="TreeNodeText">' + arr[i].title + '</div><details><summary></summary><div id="Paragraph' + i + '"><div>';
      for (var a = 0; a < arr[i].children.length; a++) {
        document.getElementById("Paragraph" + i).innerHTML = '' + arr[i].children[i].title + '';
      }

    }
  });
}

const docs = [{
  title: '01-05 I. Живые животные; продукты животного происхождения (Группы 01-05)',
  children: [{
      title: '01 Живые животные',
      children: [{
          title: '0101 ... Лошади, ослы, мулы и лошаки живые',
          children: [{
              title: '0101 2 ... лошади '
            },
            {
              title: '0101 21 000 0 чистопородные племенные животные  '
            },
            {
              title: '0101 29 ... прочие  '
            },
            {
              title: '0101 30 000 0 ослы  '
            },
            {
              title: '0101 90 000 0 прочие  '
            }
          ]
        },

        {
          title: '0105 ... Домашняя птица живая, то есть куры домашние (Gallus domesticus), утки, гуси, индейки и цесарки',
          children: [{
              title: '0105 1 ... массой не более 185 г  '
            },
            {
              title: '0105 9 ... прочие '
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: '0106 ... Живые животные прочие',
          children: [{
              title: '0106 1 ... млекопитающие  '
            },
            {
              title: '0106 2 ... рептилии (включая змей и черепах)  '
            },
            {
              title: '0106 3 ... птицы  '
            },
            {
              title: '0106 4 ... насекомые  '
            },
            {
              title: '0106 9 ... прочие '
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: '02 Мясо и пищевые мясные субпродукты',
      children: [{
          title: '0201 ... Мясо крупного рогатого скота, свежее или охлажденное',
          children: [{
              title: '0201 1 ... туши и полутуши  '
            },
            {
              title: '0201 2 ... прочие отруба, необваленные  '
            },
            {
              title: '0201 3 ... мясо обваленное  '
            }
          ]
        },

      ]
    },
    {
      title: '03 Рыба и ракообразные, моллюски и прочие водные беспозвоночные  ',
      children: [{
          title: '0301 ... Живая рыба',
          children: [{
              title: '0301 1 ... декоративная рыба  '
            },
            {
              title: '0301 9 ... живая рыба прочая  '
            }
          ]
        },

      ]
    },
    {
      title: '04 Молочная продукция; яйца птиц; мед натуральный; пищевые продукты животного происхождения, в другом месте не поименованные или не включенные   ',
      children: [{
          title: '0401 ... Молоко и сливки, несгущенные и без добавления сахара или других подслащивающих веществ',
          children: [{
              title: '0401 1 ... с содержанием жира не более 1 мас.%  '
            },
            {
              title: '0401 2 ... с содержанием жира более 1 мас.%, но не более 6 мас.%  '
            },
            {
              title: '0401 4 ... с содержанием жира более 6 мас.%, но не более 10 мас.% '
            },
            {
              title: '0401 5 ... с содержанием жира более 10 мас.%  '
            }
          ]
        },

      ]
    },
    {
      title: '05 Продукты животного происхождения, в другом месте не поименованные или не включенные   ',
      children: [{
          title: '0501 00 000 0 Человеческий волос, необработанный, мытый или немытый, очищенный или неочищенный; отходы человеческого волоса'
        },
        {
          title: '0502 ... Щетина свиная или кабанья; барсучий или прочий волос, используемый для производства щеточных изделий; их отходы',
          children: [{
              title: '0502 10 000 0 щетина свиная или кабанья и ее отходы '
            },
            {
              title: '0502 90 000 0 прочие  '
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: '0504 00 000 0 Кишки, пузыри и желудки животных (кроме рыбьих), целые и в кусках, свежие, охлажденные, замороженные, соленые, в рассоле, сушеные или копченые'
        },
        {
          title: '0505 ... Шкурки и прочие части птиц с перьями или пухом, перья и части перьев (с подрезанными или неподрезанными краями) и пух, очищенные, дезинфицированные или обработанные для хранения, но не подвергнутые дальнейшей обработке; порошок и отходы перьев или их частей',
          children: [{
              title: '0505 1 ... перья птиц, используемые для набивки; пух  '
            },
            {
              title: '0505 90 000 0 прочие  '
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: '0506 ... Кости и роговой стержень, необработанные, обезжиренные, подвергнутые первичной обработке (без придания формы), обработанные кислотой или дежелатинизированные; порошок и отходы этих продуктов',
          children: [{
              title: '0506 10 000 0 оссеин и кости, обработанные кислотой '
            },
            {
              title: '0506 90 000 0 прочие  '
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: '0507 ... Слоновая кость, панцири черепах, ус китовый и щетина из китового уса, рога, оленьи рога, копыта, ногти, когти и клювы, необработанные или подвергнутые первичной обработке, но без придания формы; порошок и отходы этих продуктов',
          children: [{
              title: '0507 10 000 0 слоновая кость; порошок и отходы  '
            },
            {
              title: '0507 90 000 0 прочие  '
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: '0508 00 000 0 Кораллы и аналогичные материалы, необработанные или подвергнутые первичной обработке; раковины и панцири моллюсков, ракообразных или иглокожих и скелетные пластины каракатиц, необработанные или подвергнутые первичной обработке, без придания формы, порошок и отходы этих продуктов'
        },
        {
          title: '0510 00 000 0 Амбра серая, струя бобровая, циветта и мускус; шпанки; желчь, в том числе сухая; железы и прочие продукты животного происхождения, используемые в производстве фармацевтических продуктов, свежие, охлажденные, мороженые или обработанные иным способом для кратковременного хранения'
        },
        {
          title: '0511 ... Продукты животного происхождения, в другом месте не поименованные или не включенные; павшие животные группы 01 или 03, непригодные для употребления в пищу',
          children: [{
              title: '0511 10 000 0 сперма бычья  '
            },
            {
              title: '0511 9 ... прочие '
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}, ]
```

```css
.treeHTML {
  line-height: normal;
}

.treeHTML details {
  display: block;
}

.treeHTML div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 0 .5em;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.2em;
}

.treeHTML div:not(:last-child) {
  /* необязательно */
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.treeHTML div:before {
  /* необязательно */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1.1em;
  height: .5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.treeHTML div:last-child:before {
  /* необязательно */
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.treeHTML summary {
  /* стилями можно задать любую форму, например, тот же плюс. Я специально не стала усложнять, чтобы можно было проще разобраться в коде */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.treeHTML details[open] summary {
  /* убрать рамку при фокусе */
  outline: none;
}

.TreeNodeText {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-left: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  min-width: 230px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* details summary:before {
    content: url("../images/plus-in-circle.png");
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: -5px;
}

details[open] summary:before {
    content: url("../images/minus-in-circle.png");
    content: "sad";
     position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: -5px;
} */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  addItems(docs, document.body);
}

function addItems(items, parent) {
  items && items.forEach((item) => {
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.innerHTML = '<div class="TreeNodeText">' + item.title + '</div>' + 
      ((item.children && item.children.length)? '<details><summary></summary><div class="paragraph"><div></details>' : '');

    addItems(item.children, d.querySelector(".paragraph"));
    parent.appendChild(d);
  });
}

const docs = [{
  title: '01-05 I. Живые животные; продукты животного происхождения (Группы 01-05)',
  children: [{
      title: '01 Живые животные',
      children: [{
          title: '0101 ... Лошади, ослы, мулы и лошаки живые',
          children: [{
              title: '0101 2 ... лошади '
            },
            {
              title: '0101 21 000 0 чистопородные племенные животные  '
            },
            {
              title: '0101 29 ... прочие  '
            },
            {
              title: '0101 30 000 0 ослы  '
            },
            {
              title: '0101 90 000 0 прочие  '
            }
          ]
        },

        {
          title: '0105 ... Домашняя птица живая, то есть куры домашние (Gallus domesticus), утки, гуси, индейки и цесарки',
          children: [{
              title: '0105 1 ... массой не более 185 г  '
            },
            {
              title: '0105 9 ... прочие '
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: '0106 ... Живые животные прочие',
          children: [{
              title: '0106 1 ... млекопитающие  '
            },
            {
              title: '0106 2 ... рептилии (включая змей и черепах)  '
            },
            {
              title: '0106 3 ... птицы  '
            },
            {
              title: '0106 4 ... насекомые  '
            },
            {
              title: '0106 9 ... прочие '
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: '02 Мясо и пищевые мясные субпродукты',
      children: [{
          title: '0201 ... Мясо крупного рогатого скота, свежее или охлажденное',
          children: [{
              title: '0201 1 ... туши и полутуши  '
            },
            {
              title: '0201 2 ... прочие отруба, необваленные  '
            },
            {
              title: '0201 3 ... мясо обваленное  '
            }
          ]
        },

      ]
    },
    {
      title: '03 Рыба и ракообразные, моллюски и прочие водные беспозвоночные  ',
      children: [{
          title: '0301 ... Живая рыба',
          children: [{
              title: '0301 1 ... декоративная рыба  '
            },
            {
              title: '0301 9 ... живая рыба прочая  '
            }
          ]
        },

      ]
    },
    {
      title: '04 Молочная продукция; яйца птиц; мед натуральный; пищевые продукты животного происхождения, в другом месте не поименованные или не включенные   ',
      children: [{
          title: '0401 ... Молоко и сливки, несгущенные и без добавления сахара или других подслащивающих веществ',
          children: [{
              title: '0401 1 ... с содержанием жира не более 1 мас.%  '
            },
            {
              title: '0401 2 ... с содержанием жира более 1 мас.%, но не более 6 мас.%  '
            },
            {
              title: '0401 4 ... с содержанием жира более 6 мас.%, но не более 10 мас.% '
            },
            {
              title: '0401 5 ... с содержанием жира более 10 мас.%  '
            }
          ]
        },

      ]
    },
    {
      title: '05 Продукты животного происхождения, в другом месте не поименованные или не включенные   ',
      children: [{
          title: '0501 00 000 0 Человеческий волос, необработанный, мытый или немытый, очищенный или неочищенный; отходы человеческого волоса'
        },
        {
          title: '0502 ... Щетина свиная или кабанья; барсучий или прочий волос, используемый для производства щеточных изделий; их отходы',
          children: [{
              title: '0502 10 000 0 щетина свиная или кабанья и ее отходы '
            },
            {
              title: '0502 90 000 0 прочие  '
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: '0504 00 000 0 Кишки, пузыри и желудки животных (кроме рыбьих), целые и в кусках, свежие, охлажденные, замороженные, соленые, в рассоле, сушеные или копченые'
        },
        {
          title: '0505 ... Шкурки и прочие части птиц с перьями или пухом, перья и части перьев (с подрезанными или неподрезанными краями) и пух, очищенные, дезинфицированные или обработанные для хранения, но не подвергнутые дальнейшей обработке; порошок и отходы перьев или их частей',
          children: [{
              title: '0505 1 ... перья птиц, используемые для набивки; пух  '
            },
            {
              title: '0505 90 000 0 прочие  '
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: '0506 ... Кости и роговой стержень, необработанные, обезжиренные, подвергнутые первичной обработке (без придания формы), обработанные кислотой или дежелатинизированные; порошок и отходы этих продуктов',
          children: [{
              title: '0506 10 000 0 оссеин и кости, обработанные кислотой '
            },
            {
              title: '0506 90 000 0 прочие  '
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: '0507 ... Слоновая кость, панцири черепах, ус китовый и щетина из китового уса, рога, оленьи рога, копыта, ногти, когти и клювы, необработанные или подвергнутые первичной обработке, но без придания формы; порошок и отходы этих продуктов',
          children: [{
              title: '0507 10 000 0 слоновая кость; порошок и отходы  '
            },
            {
              title: '0507 90 000 0 прочие  '
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          title: '0508 00 000 0 Кораллы и аналогичные материалы, необработанные или подвергнутые первичной обработке; раковины и панцири моллюсков, ракообразных или иглокожих и скелетные пластины каракатиц, необработанные или подвергнутые первичной обработке, без придания формы, порошок и отходы этих продуктов'
        },
        {
          title: '0510 00 000 0 Амбра серая, струя бобровая, циветта и мускус; шпанки; желчь, в том числе сухая; железы и прочие продукты животного происхождения, используемые в производстве фармацевтических продуктов, свежие, охлажденные, мороженые или обработанные иным способом для кратковременного хранения'
        },
        {
          title: '0511 ... Продукты животного происхождения, в другом месте не поименованные или не включенные; павшие животные группы 01 или 03, непригодные для употребления в пищу',
          children: [{
              title: '0511 10 000 0 сперма бычья  '
            },
            {
              title: '0511 9 ... прочие '
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}, ]
```

```css
.paragraph {
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: Больше спасибо, разобрался!